# SQL query taking "too" long - select with distinct and max

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the scenario:

A table with POSITION and a value associated for each position, BUT I have always 4 values for the same position, so an example of my table is:

```
position | x| values 
1 | x1 | 0
1 | x2 | 1
1 | x3 | 1.4
1 | x4 | 2
2 | x1 | 3
2 | x2 | 10
2 | x3 | 12.4
2 | x4 | 22
```

I need a query that returns me the MAX value for each unique position value. Now, I am querying it with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (position) AS p, (SELECT MAX(values) AS v FROM MYTABLE  WHERE position = p) FROM MYTABLE;
```

It took me 1651 rows in set (39.93 sec), and 1651 rows is just a test for this database (it probably should have more then 1651 rows.

What am I doing wrong ? are there any better way to get it in a faster way ?

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers.,

Comment: What are the indexes on MYTABLE ? Where do the execution plan stays stuck ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the GroupBy-Clause:

```
SELECT Position, MAX(VALUES) FROM TableName
GROUP BY Position
```

Also, have a look at the documentation (about groupby): 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: No idea, this seems to answer the question, +1

Comment: You're +8 so far, I wouldn't worry about a single down-vote in the long run. You can't control it, for the most part you can't explain it, people down-vote for all kinds of reasons, most of them inappropriate IMHO. If you let single down-votes bother you, I suspect you won't last long here.

Comment: Don't worry mate, it's not bothering me. I just wonder about the reasoning. Thanks anyway for the encouraging words.

Comment: I know. I used to wonder too. But the comments about "why the downvote" and "please undo the downvote" just turn into meaningless noise. 99% of the time the person who down-voted is not going to come back to correct it, and the other 1% will probably do so even without the comments. <shrug>

Comment: You're right. I'm not really after reputation anyway. My goal is just to help people. Thanks for sharing your experience, it won't happen again (already deleted comment) ;)

Comment: +1 . . . You have my upvote partially out of sympathy.  Your were first and you are correct.

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you, but that is not quite correct. The others below me were one minute ahead.

Comment: @FabianBigler . . . The time stamp on your answer is 18:57:29.  For the other two, it is 18:58:48 and 18:58:12.  Your answered first ;)  You can see the time stamp by hovering your mouse over the "answered xx minutes ago" line (it was Aaron Bertrand who first explained that to me).

Comment: Thank you. 1651 rows in set (0.04 sec)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for teaching. I thought I could rely on 'answered xx minutes ago' ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT position AS p, MAX(values) AS v
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY p;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT position AS p, MAX(`values`) AS v FROM MYTABLE 
 GROUP BY position
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62486/2)

OUTPUT:

```
    P | V
    1 | 2
    2 | 22
```