# MySQL query response taking too long

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently doing some MySQL queries on a large database which is taking extremely long to reply (10 mins each time). I understand the query is complex, but I really do need the time to be rapidly cut as it is halting all other processes while the script (PHP) waits for the response.

Here is the current query (still new to MySQL so I'm sure there's much to be improved) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM `saved_users`
    WHERE referral_from IN(SELECT DISTINCT `referral`
                           FROM accounts 
                           WHERE owner = '{$owner}'
                           AND `use` = '1') 
    AND username NOT IN(SELECT username FROM `signup_history` 
                        WHERE owner = '{$owner}') 
    ORDER BY date_added DESC, 
             user_type = 'mod' DESC, 
             scrape_type = DESC 
    LIMIT {$limit}
```

Thanks to all suggestions.

EDIT: EXPLAIN returned this:

```
1 PRIMARY saved_users ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 49101 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 
3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY signup_history ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 59229 Using where 
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY accounts ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 38 Using where; Using temporary
```

Comment: Put an explain before that query and run it,edit your question with the results.First look,mysql is bad with IN subqeries, you need to use JOINs

Comment: Start with debugging yourself: look up what `EXPLAIN` does, and use it. Then, look up what it shows, and what things to look for: these are non-indexed joins. Then add the correct joins, if needed. If you still have an issue, we can only help you if you THEN show is not only the query, but the database as well.

Comment: That's actually 3 queries! Not one! And use `group by` instead. It helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699533/sql-query-taking-too-long-select-with-distinct-and-max

Comment: @Mihai `1  PRIMARY  saved_users  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 49101  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  signup_history  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 59229  Using where
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  accounts  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 38  Using where; Using temporary`

Comment: Lot of things happening in the query and there are potential part within the query to make it slow, `1-subquery`, `2-where conditions`,`3-order by` 2nd and 3rd are mainly relies on the indexes on the tables, and 1st could be converted to join.

Comment: `scrape_type = desc limit`? that's invalid sql... in other words, as written above, that query is illegal, therefore it should return instantly...

Comment: Does that query even compile? `ORDER BY user_type = 'mod'` is that legal syntax?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: that part is valid. mysql will typecast the boolean result to an integer, giving you a "virtual" 1/0 field to sort on.

Comment: I've made the table names generic to avoid confusion, it does indeed compile IRL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `username` is unique in `users`.  Also, it is often better to use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` rather than `IN`/`NOT IN`.  So, I would start by rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT su.username
FROM saved_users su
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM accounts
              WHERE r.referral = su.referral_from AND
                    owner = '{$owner}' AND
                    `use` = '1'
             ) AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM `signup_history` sh
                 WHERE su.username = sh.username AND
                       sh.owner = '{$owner}'
                ) 
ORDER BY date_added DESC, 
         user_type = 'mod' DESC, 
         scrape_type DESC 
LIMIT {$limit} ;
```

For this query, I would suggest the following indexes:  `users(date_added, user_type, scrape_type, user_name)`, `referrals(referral, owner, use)`, and `signup_history(username, owner)`.

Comment: Perfect, as a noobie to MySQL I had no idea about the importance of index's...After adding them and rewriting the query it completes in seconds. Thank you all & especially Gordon.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is an excellent introduction to indexes and how to use them properly.